# Passing an array to a function and escaping double quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am generating dynamic HTML and want to pass an array to the calling function. The array is also being dynamically generated.

The contents of pinfoarray  are somewhat like this "Ice Hockey","Junior Basketball","Ladies Soccer"

```
var theHost = "<a href='#someDialog' onclick='chnghost(' + pinfoarray + ');' data-toggle='modal' class='button'>Change</a>";
```

How can make it send the array to the calling function  without an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly terminate the string and encode the parameter.  You also need to guard against reserved characters in your data (`escapeHtml`).

```
var theHost = "<a href='#someDialog' onclick='chnghost(" + escapeHtml(JSON.stringify(pinfoarray)) + ");' data-toggle='modal' class='button'>Change</a>";
```

If you're using jQuery, you can implement escapeHtml like so:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
    return $("<div/>").text(text).html();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about making it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/w7LYc/):

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');

anchor.href = '#someDialog';
anchor.setAttribute('data-toggle','modal');
anchor.className='button';

anchor.onclick = function(){
  chnghost(pinfoarray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the string double quote to put a javascript variable:

```
var theHost = "<a href='#someDialog' onclick='chnghost('" + pinfoarray + "');' data-toggle='modal' class='button'>Change</a>";
```